# Wordpress Woocommerce : How to add slider revolution on category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, slider

hello i've a problem about showing the slider revolution on category page on wordpress woocommerce.
So I want layout & view like this :
[I want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRToS.png)

i've try to add shortcode to category but the result of category not like i want, the layout like this :
[not I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8sei.png)

can someone help me?

Comment: you can customize the shortcode.

Comment: can you give me example? @vel

Comment: can post your shortcode?

Comment: here my shortcode  : [rev_slider alias="showcase-carousel"][/rev_slider] @vel

Comment: you can create a own shortcode for slider?.

Comment: sorry i can't..

Answer (score 2):

You can add a predefined slider at the top of a woocommerce archive page using the action `woocommerce_before_main_content` or `woocommerce_archive_description`.

In the function that will be call, use `do_shortcode()`.

```
  add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'display_revslider');

 function display_revslider(){
        echo do_shortcode('revslider'); //arrange this to get the right shortcode with category if need
 }
```

Or by using the php function of the plugin

```
function rev_slider_to_archive_pages() {
        if ( is_product_category() ) {
            if (function_exists('putRevSlider')) {  putRevSlider("default");  
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'rev_slider_to_archive_pages',21 );
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

sample carousel slider code

```
        function product_carousel_func() {
            $Inc=0;
           $args=array(
                      'post_type' =>'product',
                      'product_cat' =>'',
                      'posts_per_page' =>20,
                     'orderby' => 'rand'
                      );

        $wc_query = new WP_Query($args);

          $carouselSlider = '<ol class="carousel-indicators ">';
              $output.='';
                if ($wc_query->have_posts()){
           while ($wc_query->have_posts()){
            $wc_query->the_post();
            global $product;
                        $imgurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($product->id));
            $ActiveClass='';
            if($Inc==0){
             $ActiveClass='active';
            }

            $carouselSlider .= '<li data-target="#mycarousel1" data-slide-to="'.$Inc.'" class="'.$ActiveClass.'"></li>';

                    if($Inc%2==0) {

                         $output.='<div class="item '.$ActiveClass.'">
                             <div class="container">
                              <div class="row carouselrow">';
                      $OddClass ='cs_oddslider';
                    }else{
                      $OddClass ='cs_evenslider';
                    }
                 $output.='<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6  '.$OddClass.'">   
                            <img src="'.$imgurl[0].'" class="img-responsive img-circle">
                             <div class="carousel-caption " id="carousel">
                               <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 paradiv">
                                <p class="">'.get_the_title().'</p>
                                <button type="button" class="">SHOP NOW</button>
                               </div>
                             </div>  
                             </div>'; 

                if($Inc%2!=0) {
                         $output.='</div></div></div>';
                  }
            $Inc++;

                  }
            }


         $carouselSlider .= '</ol>';

            return '<div class="container-fluid "><div id="mycarousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">'.$carouselSlider.'<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">'.$output.'</div></div> </div></div></div>';
        }

        add_shortcode( 'product_carousel', 'product_carousel_func');
```

Comment: add product category to here .   'product_cat' =>'',